# Creating a dictionary of lists from a single list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, structure

I have a question about dicts. I'm a noob and have been looking through this topic extensively, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. What I am trying to do is take this huge list I have from a text file(12 million terms), put it in a dict, and take items that share certain characteristics and put them in one list in the dict so when I search through the dict, every element with that characteristic is displayed.

Example of some list elements:

```
0022 hello https:example.com/blah

0122 john https:example.com/blah

3502 hello https:example.com/blah
```

Now according to the data above, I would like to have a dict element which is a list of every time the word "hello" appears and with "hello" as the key, so when I search "hello" I would return

```
0022 hello https:example.com/blah

3502 hello https:example.com/blah
```

Any tips on how to do this efficiently?

I know a database is probably a faster and better solution, but I know nothing about DB, I'm not even a CS student I'm just taking an elective. Thank you for your help

Comment: check out `collections.defaultdict(list)`

Comment: If this is homework, you may want to show your efforts first

Comment: If you have files with millions of lines, you need more ram to fit all in dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, a `defaultdict(list)` is perfect for doing this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        key = line.split()[1]
        data[key].append(line)

print(''.join(data['hello']))
```

Which would display the lines:

```
0022 hello https:example.com/blah
3502 hello https:example.com/blah
```

Comment: Thank you a bunch :)  I had looked into defaultdict but couldn't work out the logic

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `pandas` solution:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['0022 hello https:example.com/blah',
       '0122 john https:example.com/blah',
       '3502 hello https:example.com/blah']

df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(' ') for x in lst],
                  columns=['code', 'name', 'url'])

df['code-url'] = list(zip(df['code'], df['url']))
d = df.groupby('name')['code-url'].apply(list).to_dict()

# {'hello': [('0022', 'https:example.com/blah'),
#            ('3502', 'https:example.com/blah')],
#  'john':  [('0122', 'https:example.com/blah')]}
```